# Add reference deselected in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, project

I am trying to open a existing project in visual studio 2010 using

```
   new->project from existing code
```

and selecting visual c# as the language. When I run it, I get errors. Later I heard from the person who created the project that I have to add few references, which are present in the references folder in the project itself. It comes in the side window - solution explorer.

However, when I right click on that folder to add as references, that option is 'greyed', or disabled. How Can I correct this?

Comment: Trying to add a reference while the debug is running?

Comment: Are you trying to open an existing project/solution with its own .csproj/.sln file? If so, New -> Project.. it's not the right path. Try instead with Open project. You cannot add references to a project if none is currently opened.

Comment: @Steve Yes. wat is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Add the reference when you are not debugging. (Before hitting F5, F10, F11 or whatever command you use to debug the program)

Comment: @Steve I gave it so in the normal mode, but I cant find any projects in the selection provided. Can you please tell me, how do it properly, from first? Am trying to run this project. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Steve when I click on add reference, the project name and directory are empty.

Comment: It is a broad topic. The best thing you can do is to stop a little and try to understand the basics of project referencing. These pages on MSDN are the most complete reference (no pun intended) to the argument. [Managing Solutions, Projects and Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbzbtw81.aspx)

Comment: @Steve if you dont mind, I could send you my project file. Can you please tell me how to get it running after opening the project and adding the references?

Comment: Post it on a public share site (pastebin, dropbox, skydrive, gdrive) and share the link here

Comment: @Steve https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwT5z-GBaUvMaS1hTml1Z0owY0k&usp=sharing I have shared the lin

Comment: A simple zip file please.

Comment: @Steve done https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwT5z-GBaUvMOVRfdmxfUlAtNGc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLLs named `freeglut.dll` and `glut32.dll` are not COM or NET components. You cannot add them as references to your project (You have 4 solutions in your archive, I have choosen the one named `fwa_annimate` but I think the problem is the same).

The DLL named `Tao.FreeGlut.dll` needs these files in the same directory where you application run to work. So the easiest way to resolve your problem is to select the two DLLs inside Visual Studio and change the property `Copy to Output Directory` from `Copy Never` to `Copy Always`.

In this way, when you start to debug your app, the VS IDE will copy the two files to the BIN\DEBUG or BIN\RELEASE directory where you app runs when launched inside the VS IDE.

Of course, you need to deploy all these file when you distribute your application.

(By the way, I have no idea what is supposed to do)